# How to calculate ruby hash in JavaScript?

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a use case to send the hashcode of the payload along with the payload in the request.

My Client is Ruby but Servers are both Rails and Node.

What is the best way to create a hash code for the payload (any Ruby HashMap)?

How can I create the same hashcode on the other server?

```
>> x = {:name=>"John", :age=>30, :cars=>{:car1=>"Ford", :car2=>"BMW", :car3=>"Fiat"}} 
>> x.hash
-4250725627701565010
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to use well-known language independent hash algorithm? Like MD5, SHA1 and so on.

Comment: Is there any helper that cleans the payload to get the same form on the client side and on the server side? It has to support the nested JSON as well.

Comment: For JS there is `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible.

The *only* guarantees that Ruby makes about the hashcode are:

- Two objects that are `eql?` have the same hashcode.
- The hashcode of an object does not change, unless it is mutated.
- The hashcode is an `Integer`. It *may* be truncated to a fixed-width integer in certain methods.

In particular, the following are *not* guaranteed:

- There is no guarantee that a Ruby implementation uses any particular hashing algorithm.
- There is no guarantee that the hash value of an object will be the same between different Ruby implementations.
- There is no guarantee that the hash value of an object will be the same between different versions of the same Ruby implementation.
- There is no guarantee that the hash value of an object will be the same between different processes of the same version of the same Ruby implementation.
- There is no guarantee that the hash value of an object will be the same between different runs of the same code within the same process of the same version of the same Ruby implementation.

In fact, several Ruby implementations randomize hashcodes for security purposes.

In other words, there isn't even a way *in Ruby* to know what the hashcode for an object will be at runtime, so there is *most definitely* no way to know that in ECMAScript.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an alternative hashing algorithm, such as [SHA256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), this will give the same result in Ruby and Javascript.

One must be careful however, the hashes will only match if the inputs are *exactly* the same.

**Ruby**

```
require 'json'
require 'digest/sha2'

x = {:name=>"John", :age=>30, :cars=>{:car1=>"Ford", :car2=>"BMW", :car3=>"Fiat"}} 
json = JSON.generate(x)
print "Hash: " + (Digest::SHA2.hexdigest json)
```

**Node.js**

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

const x = { name: "John", age: 30, cars: { car1: "Ford", car2: "BMW", car3: "Fiat" }};
const json = JSON.stringify(x);
const hash = crypto.createHash("SHA256").update(json, "utf8").digest("hex");
console.log("Hash:", hash);
```

We'll get the same result in both cases:

```
Hash: 1b5299251d2e9bf775bc4cf34a017c829d93866ac9563b04e2b14b6b3d291067
```